# Update software in the software center (Shotwell and Digikam)

Tags: software-center, shotwell, digikam

I'm trying to use the software center to get updated packages. I would like to like to update some beloved packages to the latest stable version: Shotwell (0.20.1) and Digikam (4.4.0).

I recently updated Ubuntu to 14.04. Do you know where can we I can get the software center to open the access to these recent versions?

Kind regards

Maxime Leloup

Answer (score 0):

The version that is displayed in the software centre is the most recent version available in the Ubuntu repositories. There are often more up to date versions available directly from the developer, but in order to install these you must install via PPA. See [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) to learn how to do this.

The PPA for Shotwell is `ppa:yorba/ppa`

The PPA for Digikam is `ppa:msylwester/digikam`